# Multi display issue with Ubuntu GNOME 14.04

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gdm

Fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 with 3 displays (fglrx driver).
I can correct the screens order in System Settings / Display but it is not saved when I close the session and reopen it.

Screens order in GDM is also wrong. Copy/pasting the .config/monitors.xml file into /var/lib/gdm/.config/ doesn't change anything.

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I use the Nvidia 331 Driver and no matter what Tool I use, the Display order always changes after a restart. So it
Using a xorg.conf doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have the same issue as well with a fresh (clean) install. All that was preserved was the `/home` partition. `/` was wiped completely.

Comment: same problem, it is every time gnome shell (re)starts. nb: no problem with unity desktop on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: i've reposted the question as not satisfied with current answers http://askubuntu.com/questions/467777/ubuntu-14-04-gnome-3-10-external-display-settingsgnome-shell-restart

Comment: Apparently a reported bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1292398, but I don't understand the problem. How are the screens not in order?

Comment: @Braiam, the "edge" of the display is in the wrong spot.  Whereas normally there is a boundary along the outside the viewable area with a traversable barrier between the two monitors, the traversable barrier is is on the outer edge of the two monitors. In other words,to get to the leftmost (secondary) monitor, you have to move the mouse cursor to the right

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have the same issue

seems like `gnome-settings-daemon` is not loading monitors.xml at  startup

my work around is to run this command

```
pkill -9 -f gnome-settings-daemon
```

as a "Startup Application"

i have documented this in my [ubuntu 14.04 update and problems](http://oct.im/upgrade-1204lts-to-1404-lts-problems-and-fixes.html) post

not sure if there is a better solution

Comment: Works great ! Thanks for this workaround. I hope they will find the root cause since GDM has also the same problem.

Comment: +1 mate I just googled clicked and solved , awesome ubuntu community

Comment: It still doesn't save the monitor setup for me, but it solves some other display problems. I need to explicitly add `r` (restart), though, to the end of `pkill -9 -f gnome-settings-daemon`.

Comment: This creates another problem in my case, makes the first desktop unusable (like it doesn't refresh and keeps shadows of closed windows in it) , any other options? I know yesterday there was a new LTS version released, but since this is a problem for two years at least i'm amazed at no bug-fix in part of ubuntu devs...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug to me. If you'd like to see it corrected I would suggest that you mark [on the official report that this bug affects you](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1292398).

Answer (score 3):

There is one more workaround:
[Link to article](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/309-ubuntu-dual-display-monitor-position-lost%20Link%20to%20article)

It basically says that ~/.config/monitors.xml is not applied on startup. So the author created a script which basically does something like this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --pos 1920x0 --output CRT1 --pos 0x0
```

...and adds this to Gnome startup programs.

Comment: you can also use arandr to create those monitor config shell scripts, but the problem is that the bug occurs at gnome-shell start which doesn't launch the app in the startup list...so i've re-asked the question http://askubuntu.com/questions/467777/ubuntu-14-04-gnome-3-10-external-display-settingsgnome-shell-restart