# Ubuntu 14.04 Dual Monitor Position reset at reboot

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

How can I make the monitor settings be saved after reboot?

I have configured my monitor on my **Lenovo T410S** like this:

[image]

after reboot its however reset to this:

[image]

Interestingly, my monitor.xml looks the way I wanted it:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
  <clone>no</clone>
  <output name="LVDS1">
      <vendor>LEN</vendor>
      <product>0x4036</product>
      <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      <width>1440</width>
      <height>900</height>
      <rate>60</rate>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>180</y>
      <rotation>normal</rotation>
      <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
      <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
      <primary>no</primary>
  </output>
  <output name="VGA1">
  </output>
  <output name="HDMI1">
  </output>
  <output name="DP1">
  </output>
  <output name="HDMI2">
  </output>
  <output name="HDMI3">
      <vendor>DEL</vendor>
      <product>0x4067</product>
      <serial>0x3134374c</serial>
      <width>1920</width>
      <height>1080</height>
      <rate>60</rate>
      <x>1440</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <rotation>normal</rotation>
      <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
      <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
      <primary>yes</primary>
  </output>
  <output name="DP2">
  </output>
  <output name="DP3">
  </output>
  <output name="VIRTUAL1">
  </output>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi display issue with Ubuntu GNOME 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450767/multi-display-issue-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04)

Comment: I think its a duplicate of another issue (http://askubuntu.com/questions/450767/multi-display-issue-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04). Just flagged it.

Answer (score 1):

`xorg.conf` is where you can make persistent changes. It should be saved in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

An example of the server layout portion would be something like

`Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "seat0"
        Screen          "screen0"       0                   0
        Screen          "screen1"       1920                   0
        InputDevice     "mouse0"        "CorePointer"
        InputDevice     "keyboard0"     "CoreKeyboard"

EndSection`

Where screen1 is 1920 pixels to the right of screen0. Your screen0 and screen1 will also have to be configured.  You can do so by running `sudo X -configure` when there is no X session (recovery mode can do this) and then save the `xorg.conf.new` file. When you have a configuration you would like to test, write it to `/etx/X11/xorg.conf`. Don't forget to backup your working xorg.conf if you have one.

Comment: To identify the screens do I need to write `LVDS1` instead of `screen0`?

Comment: I don't think so. Screen0 is just the name you give to what points to the monitor and driver for the monitor. Did you do the `sudo X -configure?` [Xorg manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html)

Comment: Hm. I went to recovery mode and chose `root shell prompt`. When I typed `sudo X -configure` it failed because it couldn"t create a lockfile. Any other way I can access this?

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Lee there is another workaround. I marked this question as duplicate.