# ubuntu 14.04 + gnome 3.10 + gnome-shell restart

Tags: gnome, scripts

Is there a way to ask gnome-shell to run a shell script every time it starts?

(Like after a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd>, not on Login)

**NB:** If you think it's about the start-up list, it's not : do a <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> and tell me if the apps in start-up list are launched: They're not (at least not on my setup).

Unfortunately, through a shell script it's not working yet :

```
#!/bin/bash
 gnome-shell --replace
 sleep 10
## reset screen config
 xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output DP1 --off --output eDP1 --off --output VGA1 --off

## reset keyboard
setxkbmap fr
```

the xrandr command is working as expected on startup

if i type in terminal sh rgnome.sh, gnome is restarted, but the next commands don't seem to get executed (and if i close the terminal it kills gnome); i'm not versed in shell scripting, so i may be doing something obvious very wrong

Comment: If it's a bug and it's reported, you should wait until they fix it. Through in SO asking for workarounds for bugs is ok, here's not.

Comment: ok mister, let's rephrase

Comment: so i have to repost now I guess until someone with half a brain and a real ubuntu expert can answer, really feeling this place is run by noobs

Comment: How is Alt + f2 +r different from Alt+F2?

Comment: @mikakun, usually you should use your .bashrc or .bash_profile files to execute this kind of scripts, but you're questions lacks some details about what you really want to do that might keep the `experts` at a distance, so, what do you want to achieve at gnome-shell start ?

Comment: r is the gnome restart shortcut you use in alt+f2  @Jobin it's alt+f2 then r (i think my post was edited by some guy that didn't understand it, otherwise apo for the imprecision)

Comment: decebal, i want to properly work around the gnome bug that mess with monitors.xml every time gnome starts or restarts (after that r command), fixing it only on start-up not enough; nb : my first question was detailed but then i got policed by this @Braiam , then mark as duplicate by  karel... (askubuntu is a grand incoherent mess if you ask me)

Comment: @decebal i've tested a command in .bashrc, it's executed on startup but not on gnome restart, i don't know about .bash_profile (no .bash_profile in my home folder)

Comment: ALT+F2 + 'r' seems to be a shortcut to the command gnome-shell --replace (http://dryja.info/gnome-shell-quick-reload-via-console-like-alt-f2-and-r/). I am also interested in this because of this other issue I have http://askubuntu.com/questions/465412/how-can-i-debug-why-gnome-settings-daemon-localeexec-is-not-started-on-login so I'll try to help you out in this and investigate later today.

Comment: @adosaiguas yes it restarts gnome while leaving the session opened, but this gnome starting process is full of bugs like the one that bother me : it's messing with monitors.xml; there is a work around on start-up (i add a command that reset my display config) which works fine, but if i just restart gnome (alt f2 then r) i then have to reset manually my display config; the bug is on low priority on launchpad ...

Comment: One idea would be to create a shell script available within your path, maybe call it r.sh. that script should call the gnome-shell --replace, and then the commands you use to fix your display config. The other option is to investigate what that replace command does and see if wee can hook some script once it is restarted.

Comment: sounds like a neat and simple solution to work around that bug  (feeling stupid now i didn't think about this alone!), do add an answer so i can give the bounty - first option only as second option is not worth the pain for my aim especially if we consider gnome dev may fix those bugs one day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shell script available within your path, maybe call it r.sh.

That script should call the gnome-shell --replace command, and then the commands you use to fix your display config.

You might need to wait a couple of seconds before running those commands in order to wait for the replace to succeed.

EDIT:

The script might be something along the lines of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-shell --replace
sleep 2
fix-your-display-commands
```

Comment: how can you delay an execeution in shell ? what about `&&` (i thought it was executing the command after after the command before)

Comment: I'm not sure how the replace works, you'll have to try it out. If executing just after running the command is enough (like you are trying) then we are ok, if not, you might need to call the sleep command before...

Comment: no luck so far unfortunately (see edited question)

Comment: what happens if you run them step by step from ALT+F2 prompt? First replace, then xrandr?

Comment: something weird happened : i tested gnome-shell --replace in alt+f2 & it did reset the proper display config on its own... but it did it just once... the xrandr command always work rom alt+f2 or the normal terminal as long as it's not after && or in the same script as the gnome --replace

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script does not work because the `xrandr` command is waiting for the `gnome-shell --restart` to exit. Since that does not happen while gnome is running, the `xrandr` command is not executed. You need to tell your script to run it in the background, that way the subsequent commands will also be run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Start gnome-shell in the background. That's what the & does
gnome-shell --replace &
sleep 10
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output DP1 --off --output eDP1 --off --output VGA1 --off
```

Now, save the script somewhere in the global `$PATH`, for example as `/usr/bin/rgnome.sh`, make it executable (`sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/rgnome.sh`) and then instead of running <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and `rgnome.sh`.

Comment: great thanks ! gnome-shell restart still messes up my keyboard config though, i'll google that; nb : sharing some points to adosaiguas since he came up first with the idea

Answer (score 0):

After commenting i decided that i should complete an answer:

Here's something that might help you understand how to use .bashrc and .bash_profile

[.bash_profile vs .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)

Do not worry if you don't have this file already, if you create it the shell should use it while you're logged in as the user in whose home the .bash_profile is saved.

The suggestions listed above will only work if your user has bash as default shell. So you might consider a deeper level as suggested below.

If you are interested on having the script run for all your users you should think about editing the /etc/profile file .

I think that you might find some answers in this section over [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables)

Comment: i'm busy on other stuff just now but will test asap although tbh i don't quite grasp how gnome would reload any bash file on its restart (independently of the user session that remains open on that gnome restart), have you tested that yourself ?

Comment: I have a repo that is based on this principle for customizing my zsh shell. But I only use .bashrc or .zshrc in it. At the time I was doing research around it I tried some of those explained above. I'm still not sure of what you're trying to achieve ...

Comment: This only works when restarting bash, I would be really surprised if it works with gnome-shell

Comment: i want to be able to restart gnome without screwing my multiple display config which it does (i can restart a session fine by putting some scripts in the startup list but if i just restart gnome my multiple display config has to be reset manually after that, my keyboard setting also sometimes).

Comment: I'm afraid this is completely irrelevant. `~/bash_profile` will only be sourced by `bash` when it runs a login shell. Gnome shell _might_ source `~/.profile` (though I think it doesn't) but it has absolutely no reason to source `~/.bash_profile`).